# React - within function setstate not updating state

Tags: reactjs

I have a Service inclusion form, which includes 2 file uploads, one for single file selector and one more for multiple file selector. On submit click calling a function to upload the files to firebase storage and saving the links. 
I'm updating the 'fileURLs' and 'sp_License' state in MultifileuploadHandler method. But it is not updating the state. when I do console.log of newState I cannot see the updated states.

Received follwoing error on submit

> 'FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom File object (found in field sp_License)'

any help appreciated.!

**EDIT :-**
I have updated my code.
On submit, before uploading the file,save data method is called. How can  I wait till upload is done and then call SaveData Method?

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let err = this.validate();
        if (!err) {
          this.setState({ loading: true,disChecked:false })
          this.fileupload();
          this.MultifileuploadHandler();
          this.saveData();

        }
    }
    saveData=()=>{
        let uid = this.props.auth.uid;
        let keysToRemove = ["loading", "checked", "disChecked", "open", "message"]
       let newState = Object.entries({...this.state}).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
         if(!keysToRemove.includes(key)){
             obj[key] = value
         }
         return obj
        }, {})
       console.log(newState)
        this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, newState,this.successMessage)
    }
    fileupload=()=>{
        //single org file
        const {fileURLs,sp_License}=this.state;
        const Lfilename = this.state.sp_Name + '_' + new Date().getTime();
        const uploadTask = storage.ref('License/' + Lfilename).put(sp_License);
        uploadTask
        .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
            return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        })
        .then(url => {
          //  orgFile.push({url});
             this.setState({sp_License:url})
        // orgFile=url
          //  console.log(orgFile)
        },()=>{
            console.log(sp_License)
        });
    }
    MultifileuploadHandler = () => {
        const {fileURLs,sp_License}=this.state;
        let files=[];
        var orgFile=[];

            //multi pilots file
           const storageRef = storage.ref();
            this.state.sp_PilotsLicense.forEach((file) => {
                storageRef
                    .child(`License/${file.name}`)
                    .put(file).then((snapshot) => {
                        return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                    }).then(url =>{
                        files.push({url});
                        console.log(url)
                        if(files.length===this.state.sp_PilotsLicense.length)
                        {
                            console.log('url')
                            this.setState({ fileURLs: files },()=>{
                                console.log(fileURLs)
                            });
                        }
                    })
            });


    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where exactly are you trying to see the state? How do you know the function does not update your state? Which state part are you talking about? You should narrow down your problem a little bit more and give the details as much as possible in order to get healthy suggestions.

Comment: added  more detail. please help me to get the desired result.

Comment: `setState` is an async operation. You can not see the immediate effect in the function like that. I can not follow the state update order properly but first, try to `console.log` your state in your `render` method and be sure that it is not updated.

Comment: within render console.log shows the updated state. but y it is not storing to firestore? I'm new to react, not sure whatever I'm doing correct or not.

Comment: Then, it updates it properly. Also, the last update you made to your question shows that this is not related to React. You need to examine Firebase documentation a little bit more maybe. It says you are trying to send invalid data.

Comment: when I do console.log(newState), it doesnt show updated state. I need udpated states here to send to firestore. how can I get that?

Comment: As far as I can see since your code is synchronous, before finishing the file upload you are trying to use your new state. Try to set up your logic according to that. You can't rely on your state with synchronous code. I don't understand the details in your code but maybe you can move your logic into your `MultifileuploadHandler` function.